# Bash String manipulation when string contains parentheses

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a directory full of files with the name template

```
xxx[0-9][0-9][0-9[0-9]ss(wrx-mmm).zip
```

The zip files contain a file `yrq000.dat` and I don't want to overwrite them when the files are uncompressed.

I am creating a processing script but I want to name that common file a name associated with its source zip and I'm checking the method:

```
for f in $(ls xxx*)
do
  uniquename="${f%%(wrx.*zip}"
done
```

I can't figure out how to strip that opening parens from the string.

Is that possible with the bash string manipulation the way I am doing it?
That is to say, it does not work. What do I need to add or remove so that it does work?

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Consider adding example input and the corresponding desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the dot from your pattern, i.e.:

```bsh
for f in xxx*;
do
    uniquename="${f%%(wrx*zip}";
    echo "${uniquename}";
done
```

That takes files whose names are of the form `xxx[0-9][0-9][0-9[0-9]ss(wrx-mmm).zip` and converts them to strings of the form `xxx[0-9][0-9][0-9[0-9]ss`. Is that what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yeah that did it. I see that I was using the "." as though it were a regex, when in fact it is taken as literal.

Comment: [Bash Pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: Interesting. I typically used expansion to select the "for"  range and then when I saw "$()" was a tool I began using it. I guess I made some incorrect assumptions about why my loops wood break when filenames had whitespace or non-standard characters.